# A sequence of 5 cards is drawn from a standard 52-card deck,with replacement. How many sequences will have at least one king or one queen, or both?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Total number of sequences without a king or a queen is $44^5$, so the total number of sequences with at least one occurrence of a king or a queen is $52^5 - 44^5$, is that correct?

Comment: sounds correct to me.... replacement after each one?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct......

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @user35603:  I think it does provide an answer.  OP stated a value for the number of draws and asked if it is correct.  It is.

Comment: Why the ......?

Comment: @mapierce271:  because answers are required to be 30 characters long and without the dots it is only 26.

Answer (score 0):

If a^b refers to a raised to the power of b, the answer should be (52 P 8) * 52^4, where P is the notation used in permutation.  There are 8 cards of king and queen and the problem boils down to picking one of them in any of the 5 cards.  It doesnt matter which is picked and in which turn it is picked.  That one turn is decided by (52 P 8) and other 4 cards simply dont matter.

Comment: No, OP is correct.  Your answer is many more than $52^5$, the number of draws with replacement and with no restrictions.